# Listview transparency is not working

Tags: android, listview, background, transparency, transparent

i have tried everything and nothing is working... can anybody help me make this list with a transparent background...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.myapp.Main$PlaceholderFragment2" >


<AutoCompleteTextView 
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/addproduct"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:imeActionLabel="Add" />
    <!-- REQUIRED singleline for the ime -->

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="#00000000" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly note that im using an adapter with a custom item layout and here is the layout for the -single- list item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00000000" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/TXT"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:background="#00000000" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/SEP" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/NUM" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/currency" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using #00000000 in every view that could be stoping the transparency and its no use

Update:
I have tried to .setAlpha((float) 0.0); in the code and i got the whole list to be transparent, in fact i only want the background to be and not the text in it..

Comment: I think the layout and the list have transparent backgrounds, but the background of the decor view is not ... You could look into that. If this doesn't help you more, try changing the background colors of the theme you are using.

Comment: setAlpha to your listview.

Comment: @lonut-negro if im getting u right... the layout holding this (decor view) is carrying two other layouts and both appear well transparent

Comment: @Aniruddha i have tried it and updated the question with ur approach..

Comment: Then try changing the textColor .

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting the background at all if you want it transparent.

If that doesn't work you may want to try:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: android:background="@null" is not working...
N.B.: i only started setting the background because i needed transparency... of course i didnt work without setting it..

Answer (score 0):

set listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) and for list item set background="#00000000".NOTE: now your listVIew background is it's parent background.in your xml file you are not specific any color or ... for it's parent.and if you need it's background shows device homePage you should change application theme
main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mhp.customimagebtn"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewDisplay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/black"
   android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
   </ListView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#00000000">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtItemDiscription"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
android:textColor="#343434" />




 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/list_image"
 android:layout_width="150dp"
 android:layout_height="150dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in main.class

```
list.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

this is my result
[image]

Comment: i dont think i understand what u changed in my code.... i did exactly what ur saying but only in the xml layout file

Comment: ok thanks @MHP for ur help... turned out u were right, the problem was coming from the adapter setting the background color, hence overriding the original (transparent) one

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out the the code assigns a color to the list entries in the adapter.... my bad.... thanks all for ur help, that was driving me crazy